# QSystemTrayIcon makes python crash

Tags: python, qt5, pyside

QSystemTrayIcon makes the application crash. I dont get an error in the console. Windows says AppHangB1. However, sometimes it works a few times, sometimes it crashes when first showing the context menu.

Edit:

This is my code broke down to the most important things:

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):

def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
    QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
    menu = QMenu()
    showAction = menu.addAction("Fenster anzeigen")
    exitAction = menu.addAction("Beenden")
    menu.setStyleSheet("QMenu{background-color:white; margin:2px; "
                       "font: 75 10pt Trebuchet MS;} "
                       "QMenu::item:selected{background-color:#8e0000;}")
    self.setContextMenu(menu)
    self.setToolTip("KOSE")
    exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
    showAction.triggered.connect(self.show_window)

def exit(self):
    sys.exit()

def show_window(self):
    if (loading_screen_window.windowOpacity() == 0.0):
        loading_screen_window.fadeIN()

class CancelWindow(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(CancelWindow, self).__init__()
    loader = QUiLoader()
    file = QFile("cancel.ui")
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    global cancel_screen
    cancel_screen = loader.load(file, self)
    file.close()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    #some init stuff like window pos, button- function connects...

def fadeIN(self):
    #window fade in animation

def fadeOUT(self, exit):
    #fade out animation

def ja(self):
    #button func
    self.fadeOUT(True)

def nein(self):
    #button func
    self.fadeOUT(False)
    kunden_screen.lbl_opacity.hide()
    kunden_screen.setEnabled(True)

def exit_app(self):
    QCoreApplication.exit() 

class LoadingScreen(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__()
    loader = QUiLoader()
    file = QFile("loading_screen.ui")
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    global loading_screen
    loading_screen = loader.load(file, self)
    file.close()
    self.initUI()

    #Config Thread
    self.config_thread = config()
    self.config_thread.finished.connect(self.config_finished)

    #Config Thread starten
    self.config_thread.start()

def initUI(self):
    #window init

def fadeIN(self):
    #fade animation

def fadeOUT(self):
    #fade animation

def config_finished(self):
    #function thats called when config thread is finished

class KundenSelect(QWidget):
connected = 0
cursor = None
conn_database = None

def __init__(self):
    super(KundenSelect, self).__init__()
    loader = QUiLoader()
    file = QFile("kunden.ui")
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    global kunden_screen
    kunden_screen = loader.load(file, self)
    file.close()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):      
    #window init

class config(QThread):  
def run(self):
    #config thread, reading files, database connection ...

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

global loading_screen_window
loading_screen_window = LoadingScreen()

global kunden_screen_window
kunden_screen_window = KundenSelect()
kunden_screen.lbl_opacity.hide()
kunden_screen_window.hide()

global cancel_screen_window
cancel_screen_window = CancelWindow()
cancel_screen_window.hide()

trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QIcon("icon.png"), parent=app)
trayIcon.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've googled it, but didnt find any solution. Im using PySide2 and Qt5.

Thanks

Comment: what is `loading_screen_window`?, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, thats a window thats shown when the menu point is clicked. the window is already loaded, but its opacity is set to 0. what other information should i provide? thanks

Comment: Have you read the link? It tells you that I'm asking you, but I'll tell you what we need, we need a code that is reproducible, currently your code is not because there are missing define elements, if you have many lines of code for example 200 to more It is better that you create a new project focused on your problem that is complete. We need to verify the existence of the problem to give you suggestions or possible solutions. Now do you understand what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working just changed the signal/slot syntax

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        menu = QMenu()
        showAction = menu.addAction("Fenster anzeigen")
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Beenden")
        menu.setStyleSheet("QMenu{background-color:white; margin:2px; "
                           "font: 75 10pt Trebuchet MS;} "
                           "QMenu::item:selected{background-color:#8e0000;}")
        self.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.setToolTip("KOSE")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        showAction.triggered.connect(self.show_window)

    def exit(self):
        sys.exit()

    def show_window(self):
        print("xxxxxx")
        # if (loading_screen_window.windowOpacity() == 0.0):
        # loading_screen_window.fadeIN()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QIcon("icon.png"), parent=app)
trayIcon.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Using Pyside (not Pyside2), but I don't think it would be that different here.

Comment: That is not an answer, it should be a comment that indicates that you have tested the code in PySide and you have not had any problem. Why is not it an answer ?, because it does not help to solve the problem, just check that the code that shows the asker is correct so probably the error is in another part of the asker code that has not yet shown.

Comment: @eyllanesc As I said, I "changed the signal/slot syntax".
Before the change, it didn't work.
Don't downvote me before reading the answer...

Comment: I see the same code that the author showed when I made the downvote